# Add custom checkboxes at the end of checkout/onepage

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

at the end of checkout/onepage I like to add a checkbox below the agreements. Currently there are only the terms.

I like to add an optional checkbox where user can register for a newsletter or check that the products shall be packed as present. Of course this field shall be shown in backend too so thart I can see if the order shall be a present or if the user wants the newsletter.

Can someone tell me how to do the "checkbox for presents" or newsletter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have covered the newsletter option before by doing the following:

**Add Field**

Update the template checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml to include your new checkbox,

**Use the checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after**

Using a custom module use something like

```
<events>
    <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
        <observers>
            <your_module>
                <class>your_module/observer</class>
                <method>saveOrderAfter</method>
            </your_module>    
        </observers>
    </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
</events>
```

**Get customer information in observer**

In your observer you can then get the field by

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('whatever_you_called_your_field', false);
```

You can then get the order customerid or email

```
$observer->getData('order')->getCustomerId();
$observer->getData('order')->getCustomerId();
```

At this point your could load the newsletter/subscriber model and subscribe the email or load the customer and setIsSubscribed to true.

This does not save the attribute against the order but if you create an order attribute in an install script then you could use the observer to set this against your order, though it might be safer to use the sales_order_save_before event to set the attribute against the order.

```
$installer->addAttribute(
    'order',
    'your_attribute',
        array(
            'label' => 'Newsletter',
            'type'  => 'int'
        )
);
```